# Teamviewer 9.0.32150 нужна помощь

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, kubuntu, teamviewer

Одним словом я уже зае##### так как на удаленном компьютере стоит именно эта версия ( 9.0.32150). При попытке скачать с офф сайта идет версия 9.0.2... На просторах интернета нашел под винду версию 9.0.34... но тоже не подходит, жалуется на что то несовместимое в версиях... Помогите найти ИМЕННО версию тимвивера  9.0.32150 под винду или под убунту.

Comment: пусть скачают тимвьювер квик саппорт актуальной версии или anydesk - они запускаются без установки.

Comment: @eri Там ubuntu 16, сильно урезанная, но идея очень даже хорошая

Comment: кстати недавно заработал из под firefox, chrome remote desktop, пробовал в 18-й убунте

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо вам большео, дельные советы. Но eri в который раз дает мне пищу для размышления. И так, мне надо управлять компьютером на котором стоит Teamviewer 9.0.32150. Под винду такую версию я не нашел, а на убунте мне оно не ставится из-за кучи зависимых библиотек, которые разрабы уже давным давно выкинули. Немного подумав, сам тимвивер дает возможность как быть управляемым так и управлять, что второе мне не обязательно. Я установил на удаленный компьютер Teamviewer-Host. Оно ни как вроде не мешает работать тимвиверу, и собственно я могу подключится к тому компьютеру. Для себя вопрос я решил. Всем спасибо